# How to get the "Your battery is broken" message to go away?

Tags: power-management, notification

Every time I turn on my computer, I see a message saying something like:

```
Your battery may be old or broken.
```

I am already aware that my battery is bad. How do I suppress this message?

Comment: Wow. This is question #1. http://askubuntu.com/questions/1

Comment: Private beta on that day perhaps

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe [these](http://linux.aldeby.org/get-rid-of-your-battery-may-be-broken-notification.html) instructions will help you to get rid of that message.

Added instructions from the link, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type in `gconf-editor`.

Navigate to `/apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/low_capacity` and untick the value.

Or a single command:

```
gconftool --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/low_capacity --type boolean false
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

If you have a machine with Windows as a dual-boot option, you can boot to Windows and let the battery recharge here. When the battery has recharged for a while, you can boot to Ubuntu and let it do the rest.

Comment: The message mean the maximum power of the battery is lower then specified by manufacturer. Probably because it is too old. Recharging cannot help.

Answer (score 6):

I run this:

```
gconftool --set /org/mate/power-manager/notify-low-power --type boolean false
gconftool --set /org/mate/power-manager/notify-low-capacity --type boolean false
```

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu mate, gconf editor is not installed by default and installing it will not help.

Instead, you should use dconf editor.
You will need to navigate to `/org/mate/power-manager` and then untick `notify-low-capacity`.